# Is there a valid symbol for "two or more" with Crow's Foot notation?

Tags: design, database-design, diagrams

I have a database design for which one entity of Class A always has at least two entities of Class B. Can I express this with valid Crow's Foot notation?

One possible idea I had was this:

[image: Crows Foot diagram]

Excuse the giant crow's foot, was a quick drawing! I know this breaks the Crow's Foot format of always having two symbols on each end. Also I'm concerned that it's not particularly obvious. I think doing a UML with `2...M` is more obvious.

So is there a way I can do this cleanly with Crow's Foot?

Comment: How are you intending to implement that in the database such that one isn't allowed?

Comment: @MichaelT Obviously not at the table design level, but I'd enforce the rule either with a trigger or with the code interface. So it's more of a business logic rule than raw DB design rule. Though it certainly is a strict rule.

Comment: The crows foot format is trying to describe the raw DB design and isn't intended to be describing the additional business logic constraints in triggers or elsewhere. Thus, that *idea* just doesn't exist in the crows foot diagram. UML describes a different abstraction of the data than the crows foot diagram does.

Comment: @MichaelT Oh right! Would the verbs in UMLs be another aspect of beyond-DB abstraction?

Comment: I'd put UML verbs in the beyond-DB abstraction. I look at it this way: UML is a high level design language. ER diagrams are a low level design language. Just as you can compile C to assembly, you can 'compile' UML to an ER diagram. Just as with the C++ to assembly compiler, not all the abstractions that were in C++ are visible in assembly - the same is true with UML and ER diagrams. If you were working by hand in assembly, you don't think about classes and virtual functions. If you are working by hand in ER diagrams, you don't think of UML verbs and abstractions.

Comment: Ok great, makes sense. Sounds like the short answer to my original question is "no" then.

Comment: That would be my take on it. Though I'll admit to not being a UML practitioner so I might be off in the analogy. ... and "no" is too short for the initial answer (and I didn't know what you were thinking at the time of the first comment).

Comment: @MichaelT: just my 2 cents: I think the comparison of UML vs. ERD to C vs assembly is not appropriate. UML has more than one diagram type, and UML class diagrams can have some additional elements, but when using them to sketch data models, they are on the pretty much same level of abstraction as ERDs.

Comment: @DocBrown think of it as one of those really bad car analogies that we so hate but keep using. I wasn't overly comfortable with the analogy myself, but it seemed to get the idea that I was thinking (however forced into the analogy - and misinformed) across...

Comment: Please, I beg you, look up the [zero, one, infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).  In design there is no such thing as 2.  Now I'm going to go have a good cry.

Comment: @CandiedOrange hah no need to cry! I've come to agreement that the DB is too low level to apply a 2 rule, but at some point in application design, a 2 rule may need to be implemented. E.g. the max number of sections in a report is 2 - that rule isn't inherently wrong, but don't put that at the DB level. Though Crow's Foot already expresses a symbol for 1 or more rather than 0 or more - isn't that an arbitrary limit?

Comment: The design need only show that a report has a configurable maximum number of sections.  No, 0 is special and may be reflected in designs.  1 is special and may be reflected in designs.  Anything else must be arbitrary.  As in, whatever the user damn well feels like configuring.  Please keep 2 out of your designs.  Every time you use a 2 a kitten loses an argument with a lawnmower. Aw now you've made me cry again.  Poor kitty. Sob. But the lawnmower did make a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no "offical" symbol for this. You can help yourself by adding a free-form commentary, or use UML instead.